# Why need launchfiles a copyright?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After copy and paste working source files from an ubuntu humble to ubuntu foxy the launch didn't work.

So I did

```
colcon test
colcon test-result --verbose
```

the long list with mainly flake8 issues starts with

```
could not find copyright notice
```

for the launch files but I can't find any notice in the documentation about launchfile copyrights.
why does this happens ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407905/why-need-launchfiles-a-copyright-?/) by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2022-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As part of the standard set of linters that you get when you use `ament_lint_auto` or call the linters manually from the CLI is one that checks for copyrights in all of your source code files. This will check C / C++ / CMake / Python files for a header containing a software license as good general practice in software development (for some licenses, like BSD and Apache 2.0 that require it in every source file). There's nothing special about launch files, they're still python files that have copyrights attached to them like any other type of software - so you're probably just seeing that error because you have copyrights everywhere else but didn't include them in your launch files.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2022-10-15**:
thanks a lot. that explains it. Thought the most open source projects have one license file valid for the source at a whole.